# Partition a similarity matrix

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, partitioning

Consider a list of sets

```
sets <- list(
  S1=c("A", "B", "C"),
  S2=c("A", "B", "D", "E"),
  S3=c("F", "G", "H"),
  S4=c("H", "I", "J"))
```

We can build a matrix showing the number of common elements between sets:

```
S <- sapply(sets, function(.s) unlist(sets) %in% .s)
S <- crossprod(S)
```

```
   S1 S2 S3 S4
S1  5  4  0  0
S2  4  6  0  0
S3  0  0  4  2
S4  0  0  2  4
```

The matrix can be used to cluster the variables into two sets which do not share any elements by partitioning it into symmetric matrices `S[1:2,1:2]` and `S[3:4,3:4]`.

Question: How can I partition a symmetric matrix into submatrices?

Comment: how do you define a subset ? you gave a specific example , buy it could have also been that  sets share variables in a non symetric way- or am i missing something?

Comment: Groups which do not share any elements.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you start with sets and then calculate your S matrix, I'm not sure whether your question is about finding super sets of the sets which contain overlapping elements or about block diagonal matrices.  I've approached it a set problem but the answer can be used to partition the matrix and extract submatrices.

The basic approach is to make a function which finds supersets containing common elements in sets.  We apply this function first to `sets` and then to the super sets containing common sets.  I've extended your sample problem to show that the solution handles more complex sets.

```
sets <- list(
S1=c("A", "B", "C"),
S2=c("F", "G", "H"),
S3=c("A", "B", "D", "E"),
S4=c("N", "O", "P"),
S5= c("J","K", "L"),
S6=c("H", "I", "J"),
S7=c("M", "N","O","Q") )

S <- sapply(sets, function(.s) unlist(sets) %in% .s)
S <- crossprod(S) 

  make_super_set <- function( xset ) {
#
#  xset should be a named list of set elements
   super_sets <- list()
   for( iset in names(xset)) {
     super_sets[[iset]] <-  names(xset)[sapply(xset, function(x) any(is.element(x, xset[[iset]])))]
   } 
super_sets 
}

# Find super sets containing common set elements
  temp_set <- make_super_set(sets)
# Find super sets contiaing overlaping sets
  super_set <- make_super_set(temp_set)
# Find unique sets of super sets
  super_set <- unique(super_set)
#  partition S matrix into submatrices
  part_mat_ord <- unlist(super_set)
  S[part_mat_ord,part_mat_ord]
# make list of submatrices
  lapply(super_set, function(x) S[x,x])
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
   S1 S3
S1  5  4
S3  4  6

[[2]]
   S2 S5 S6
S2  4  0  2
S5  0  4  2
S6  2  2  5

[[3]]
   S4 S7
S4  5  4
S7  4  6
```